# Difference between the words "to cross" and "to x"

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

I know that there is the word *cross out*, with the meaning like *to draw a line on something written that is relevant no more*. And we cross out something in lists, etc.

But could we use just the verb ***cross*** to express the meaning when we draw a cross on smth (*like to X*), but it still relevant to us in its changed condition (*being crossed*).

I need to put it in such context

> After erasing the sticker must be crossed with red lines.

We cannot *crossed out* the sticker because it still will be stick on smth. I have this feeling that it cannot be ***"out"***. So can we use just the verb ***cross*** for this? Or maybe I have the wrong feeling.

Please, help me to understand it.

Comment: No, "out" has nothing to do with the status of the sticker, just the markings on it. Since it is a phrasal verb, [*cross out*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cross-out) needs to be interpreted as a whole, rather than by the individual words. [*rub out*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rub-out) def. 1 is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ***cross*** with the following definition:

> To make or put a line across

You are correct that with the preposition ***out*** there is usually a connotation of negation.

---

You may also encounter use with ***off***. This usually has the connotation of completion rather than negation. As in, "We can cross off a few items from our to-do list."